# Add elements to inlineformset_factory using the shell

Tags: python, django, inline-formset

I need to add elements of invoice details using the shell to inlineformset_factory, my models are:

```
class InvoiceDetail(CreateUpdateMixin):
    client = models.ForeignKey('client.Client', verbose_name=_('Factura A'), blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    date = models.DateField()
    tax = models.FloatField()
    concept = models.ForeignKey(ConceptDetail, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Clave Concepto'))
    custom_concept = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Concepto'))
    amount = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_('Cantidad'))
    fee = models.FloatField(verbose_name=_('Honorarios')) 
    duty = models.FloatField(verbose_name=_('Gastos'))  
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, null=True, blank=True, related_name='detail_concepts')

class Invoice(CreateUpdateMixin):
    invoice = models.CharField(max_length=15, verbose_name=_('Número de Factura'))
    # Details to show when calls the invoice choice from menu in procedure
    # for mabe is an addenda
    title_addenda = models.CharField(max_length=80, verbose_name=_('Titulo Detalle Factura'))
    detail_addenda = models.CharField(max_length=350, verbose_name=_('Detalle Factura'))
    status = models.ForeignKey(StatusInvoice, null=True, blank=True)
```

i tried it, but doesn't work

```
In [54]: invoice_obj = Invoice.objects.get(invoice=100067)
Out[55]: <Invoice: 100067>
In [56]: inv_det = InvoiceDetail.objects.get(custom_concept='PROFESSIONAL FEES FOR THE PAYMENT OFEACH ANNUAL TAX ON PATENTS')
Out[57]: <InvoiceDetail: b'PROFESSIONAL FEES FOR THE PAYMENT OFEACH ANNUAL TAX ON PATENTS'>
In [58]: # create inlineformset_factory
In [59]: TestFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Invoice, InvoiceDetail, fields='__all__')

In [61]: test = TestFormSet(instance=invoice_obj)

In [62]: test.data
Out[62]: {}
In [63]: test.save()
Out[63]: []
```

I try to follow this [django docs inline-formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) according to the docs my steps are right, I'm doing wrong?

***Edited to add more details***

I have a migration script in which i need to add multiples InvoiceDetail objects to Invoice, for that reason i try to convert to inlineformset_factory thinking it is the right way but i don't know, being that if added directly the InvoiceDetail to the Invoice it doesn't maintain all the InvoiceDetail it only preserves the latest, if i modify my model Invoice to m2m InvoiceDetails i can preserve all the elements but i can't use a formset.all the InvoiceDetail it only preserves the latest.

Here is my script code:

```
def _get_invoice_detail(self, key, complex_dictionary):
    """
        For add correct data we need to create a formset so.
    :param complex_dictionary:
    :return:
    """
    # from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory
    # InvoiceDetailFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Invoice, InvoiceDetail, fields='__all__')
    # load all invoices from db
    _db = {}
    _concept = {}
    obj = None
    clase = None
    for i in Invoice.objects.all():
        _db[i.invoice] = i
    res = {}
    for i in ConceptDetail.objects.all():
        _concept[i.pk] = i        
    for i in complex_dictionary:
            try:
                if int(i['CCLAVE']) in self.clients:
                    _client = self.clients[int(i['CCLAVE'])]
                _client = Client.objects.get(pk=int(i['CCLAVE']))
            except:
                _client = self._client_default
            try:
                _date = datetime.date(int(i['FECHA'][0:4]), int(i['FECHA'][4:6]), int(i['FECHA'][6:8]))
            except:
                _date = datetime.date(1970, 1, 1)
            # "Invoice" instance isn't saved in the database.
            if i['FACTURA'] in _db:
                obj = _db[i['FACTURA']]
            else:
                try:
                    obj = Invoice.objects.get(invoice=i['FACTURA'])
                except:
                    exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
                    print('Error getting the Invoice Object:', key, exc_value,
                      repr(traceback.format_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)))
            if i['CLVART'] in _concept:
                clase = _concept[i['CLVART']]
            else:
                try:
                    clase = ConceptDetail.objects.get(pk=i['CLVART'])
                except:
                    exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
                    print('Error getting the ConceptDetail Object:',  i['CLVART'], exc_value,
                          repr(traceback.format_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)))
            invoice_detail = {
                'client': _client,
                'date': _date,
                'tax': int(i['IVA']),
                'concept': clase,
                'custom_concept': i['DEART1']+i['DEART2']+i['DEART3']+i['DEART4'],
                'amount': i['CANTIDAD'],
                'fee': i['HONORARIO'],
                'duty': i['DERECHOS'],
                'invoice': obj
            }
            try:
                if i[key] in res:
                    res[i[key]].append(InvoiceDetail.objects.update_or_create(**invoice_detail)[0])
                else:
                    res[i[key]] = [InvoiceDetail.objects.update_or_create(**invoice_detail)[0]]
            except:
                exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
                print('Error creating the Invoice Detail:', invoice_detail, exc_value,
                      repr(traceback.format_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)))

def create_invoice_details(self, m):
        _invoice_detail = jdft(m.fetch_dbase_table('FACTPAN.DBF')).as_frame('FACTURA')\
            .drop(['NOMBRE', 'DESC', 'PRECIO', 'SUBTOT', 'TOIVA', 'RELANEX', 'RFC', 'LASTUP'], 1)\
            .to_dict(orient='records')
        self._get_invoice_detail('FACTURA', _invoice_detail)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing here. inlineformset_factory is a function that generates formsets, which are collections of forms to allow you to and and edit objects in your web page. They don't contain elements. So it's not clear what your question is.

Comment: Using inlineformset_factory in my view, i can add multiples InvoiceDetails to Invoice, and works fine.

but i have a migration script in which i need to do the same, for that reason i try to convert to inlineformset_factory, being that if adding directly the Invoice doesn't maintain all the InvoiceDetail it only preserves the latest.

Comment: That's really not what it's for. You should add it directly: if you're having problems, you should post the code where you do that.

Comment: After i running of script code, i don't get any relation, maybe the formset is not a good decision, and i need to conserve Invoice has m2m InvoiceDetails and build a custom forms.
In [1]: invoice_obj = Invoice.objects.get(invoice=100067)
In [2]: invoice_obj.detail_concepts.all()
In [3]:  InvoiceDetail.objects.filter(invoice=100067)
Out[3]: []
Out[2]: []

Comment: Sorry, still don't understand what you are showing here. If you want to add a detail to an invoice you would just do `invoice_obj.detail_concepts.add(my_invoice_detail_obj)`.

Comment: Thanks it's i needed, i appreciate your help, and sorry to not be more clear but i don't know about this topic. where can found information about this topic, using related name and other common stuff.